# Redirect 301 doesn't work properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to perfom a 301 redirect like this:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

##This is the redirect
RewriteRule /page/old-url http://website.com/page/new-url [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]

</ifmodule>
```

But I got a url like this:

```
http://website.com/page/new-url?route=page/old-url
```

I tried many variations for instance:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /page/old-url http://website.com/page/new-url
```

But still can't fix it

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

##This is the redirect
RewriteRule ^page/old-url/?$ /page/new-url/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: I tried it, but now I get this url: http://website.com/page/old-url ,it doesn't change to the new one

Comment: That rule works fie on my Apache. Make sure this is in site root and there are no other rules before this